# NoMethodError in SessionsController#create in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController    
  def create    
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"],auth["uid"]) || 
           User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id]=user.id
    redirect_to("/sessions/sign")
  end

  def sign  

  end    
end
```

This is in User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :provider, :uid

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider=auth["provider"]
      user.uid=auth["uid"]
      user.name=auth["user_info"]["name"]
    end
  end
end
```

Error:

```
undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
```

When I sign in through facebook I get the above error

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the following exists and is not `nil`

```
auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
```

You could do

```
auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
if auth
  # do stuff
else
  # error handler
end
```

Or in your model I would check:

```
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  return unless auth
  create! do |user|
    user.provider = auth["provider"]
    user.uid      = auth["uid"]
    user.name     = auth["user_info"]["name"]
  end
end
```

Finally you can use the `try` method to deal with `nil` values, like this:

```
auth.try(:[], 'provider')
```

If `auth` is `nil`, it will return `nil`, otherwise it will return the value with the key `provider`